# URLs being altered between iOS Mail & iOS Safari (on iPhone)

Tags: url, ios6, mobile-safari, email-client

Clicking on an email link from the Mail app that had "utm_source=eCom" as part of the URL brought me Safari URL where "=eC" was replaced by "ì" (the lowercase i with an accent going left). Final result: "utm_sourceìom"

In the same instance, "utm_content=Face" was replaced with "utm_contentúce".

Other links from the same email with the same content didn't do this. Any ideas what might be causing this?